# How to remove commas and decimals from value

Tags: jquery

I have an input field where the user can enter their property value. This value then gets commas and decimals added to it on Keyup.

I'm trying to remove those commas and decimals.

This is my JS.

Currently, this removes the '£' symbol and removes any digits after the first 3 digits. How would I alter this to show up to 6 digits?

```
    $('#sd-Calculate').on('click', function () {

        var checkInput = document.getElementById("sd-property-value").value;

        var priceNum = parseInt(checkInput.replace(/£/g, ""));

        console.log(priceNum);

        if (priceNum <= 500000) {
            console.log('less than and equal to 500k');
        } 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form__field">
    <label for="sd-property-value" class="form__label">Property Value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="sd-property-value" class="sd-property-value currency input-text" name="sd-calc" />
</div>

<div class="calculator-controls">
    <p><button id="sd-Calculate" class="button">Calculate</button></p>
</div>
```

How would I alter this to show up to 8 digits?

For example

£500,000.00 gets entered but would like it returned as 500000

Comment: Can you add a few examples of input and the expected value that should be derived from it, including "difficult" cases?

Comment: I would also suggest this is an XY problem - instead of entering `50000` and having it converted to `£50,000` *then* converting back to `50000` - you could store the original `50000` as a `data-` attribute `$(this).data("value", $(this).val()` *before* messing with the user's input - then just read that data attribute back

Answer (score 0):

To convert **£500,000.00** input to  this **500000**

Make use of `slice()` method on strings and `filter()` method of arrays to filter out any number of commas(,) in your input.

```
let input = `£500,000.00`;
let arr = input.slice(input.indexOf('£')+1,input.lastIndexOf('.')).split('');

const newArray = arr.filter(item=>item!==',');
let result = parseInt(newArray.join(''));
console.log(result); // 500000
```

**NOTE:** There is an update, Now I am using filter() method. Since, there may not only be one comma(,) in the total amount. If the amount gets big the number of commas in the amount will increase. Now `filter()` takes care of all those. Rest `slice()` takes care of. This is a more general solution to your problem.

Hope that will sort your life.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that `parseInt()` will do this for you. Consider the following.

```js
$('#sd-Calculate').on('click', function() {

  var priceNum = parseInt($("#sd-property-value").val());

  console.log(priceNum);

  if (priceNum <= 500000) {
    console.log('less than or equal to 500k');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form__field">
  <label for="sd-property-value" class="form__label">Property Value: </label>
  <input type="text" id="sd-property-value" class="sd-property-value currency input-text" name="sd-calc" />
</div>

<div class="calculator-controls">
  <p><button id="sd-Calculate" class="button">Calculate</button></p>
</div>
```

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified `radix`, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

With your test of `£500,000.00`, this will fail. and result in `NaN`. So we can check it beforehand with replace.

```js
function stripCurrency(str) {
  var regex = new RegExp("$|£|,", "gi");
  str = str.replace(regex, "");
  return str;
}
$('#sd-Calculate').on('click', function() {

  var priceNum = parseInt(stripCurrency($("#sd-property-value").val()));

  if (priceNum <= 500000) {
    console.log('less than or equal to 500k.', priceNum);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form__field">
  <label for="sd-property-value" class="form__label">Property Value: </label>
  <input type="text" id="sd-property-value" class="sd-property-value currency input-text" name="sd-calc" value="£499,999.99" />
</div>

<div class="calculator-controls">
  <p><button id="sd-Calculate" class="button">Calculate</button></p>
</div>
```

You can use a Regular Expression and `.replace()` to strip out a whole list of characters.